Can we call apex method with the same name but with different letter case in another class?
Can I call a method in another class with the same method name but with different cases.
For example a method testMethod() is in classA. And itsl is called as ClassA.TestMethod() in ClassB. Will it work?

Welcome to SFSE! Please take the tour and read How to Ask. You will need to edit your question to include more details.

In the same class? no. In another class? almost certainly yes. This is assuming you're working entirely within Apex (no JS/Aura/LWC). Please [edit] your question to include an example of what you're trying to do. If you're running into any errors, you should copy/paste the entirety of the error verbatim.

Yes, it's possible to call a method in another class with the same method name but different cases. For instance, if you have a method named testMethod() in ClassA, and you call it as ClassA.TestMethod() from ClassB (as long as testMethod() is public), the code should work as expected. However, your IDE might show a warning for case mismatch. But in terms of functionality, it should work fine.

If the IDE knows about Apex (e.g. VS Code), it should be able to resolve the symbols correctly anyways.
